# Efficient way of iterating rows in pandas

Tags: sql, performance, python-2.7, pandas, oracle11g

I have a dataframe in pandas containing the following information
[image: showing only 5 entries]

Using a for loop for each entry in the TRANSACTION_ID, I am calling the following function,

```
def checkForImages(TransNum):
"""pass function a transaction number and get the string with image found information then store that
string into the same row in a new column"""
try:
    cursor.execute('select CAMERA_TYPE from VEHICLE_IMAGE where TRANSACTION_ID=' + str(TransNum))
    result = ''
    for img_type in cursor:
        result = result + img_type[0]
    if result == '':
        result = 'No image available'
    print 'Images found: ' + str(TransNum) + " "+ result
    resultSort = result.split()
    resultSort.sort()
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(resultSort)):
        result = result + " " + resultSort[i]
    cursor.close()
    return result
except Exception as e:
    # print 'Error occured while getting image references: ', e
    pass
```

This function returns a string which is either 'No images available' or has the image information if found. I have to create a new column in the dataframe populated with this result so my final dataframe should look like this

[image]

My question is: How can I speed up this process? Using for loop on rows with 100k+ entries is extremely slow and painful. I have looked into functions like **dataframe.map** and **dataframe.apply** but haven't been able to get it working. Other options I see is using cython or multiple threads. In which option should I invest my time? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post actual data... not an image.  Make it easy for us to help you by providing data we can copy/paste [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query Oracle for each transaction and then additionally aggregate fetched data for each transaction in a loop - it's very inefficient.

First i would create a "mapping" DataFrame like as follows:

```
transaction_id               images
           111   No image available
           112           FRONT REAR
           113             OVERVIEW
```

this can be done using [Oracle's LISTAGG function](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
qry = """
select
  transaction_id,
  NVL(listagg(camera_type, ' ') within group (order by camera_type), 'No image available') as images
from vehicle_image group by transaction_id
"""

# `engine` - is a SQLAlchemy engine connection    ...
cam = pd.read_sql(qry, con=engine, index_col=['transaction_id'])
```

after that we can use `Series.map()` method:

```
df['Image_Found'] = df.transaction_id.map(cam.images)
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks alot